# SSDT TSqlModel.DeleteObjects method doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I've been trying to use the TSqlModel method DeleteObjects to programmatically remove certain users from a Database project. The problem is that when I call the method, the user remains in the model. I wonder if I am calling the method correctly. Here's something close to what I am doing:

```
modelFromDacpac.DeleteObjects(@"DOMAIN\user");
```

When I run the following code to see if it's really gone, the user is still there!

```
var tst_delete= modelFromDacpac.GetObjects(User.TypeClass, new ObjectIdentifier(@"DOMAIN\user"), DacQueryScopes.Default).FirstOrDefault();
```

`tst_delete` is non-null and has a name that matches `"DOMAIN\user"`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to the `DeleteObject` method call, I insert the following line - where the sqlobj object is a `TSqlObject` referring to the user I am trying to delete

```
//For some reason, the logins aren't scripted objects within the DACPAC, and so cannot be deleted using the DeleteObjects method - or maybe they simply cannot be found.
modelFromDacpac.ConvertToScriptedObject(sqlobj, "DOMAIN_user.sql");
```

Then I call the `DeleteObject` method as follows:

```
modelFromDacpac.DeleteObjects("DOMAIN_user.sql");
```

I'm not sure *why* this works, but it does. My guess is that the `DeleteObject` method is pretty picky about how and where it expects to find objects. Or, maybe some objects, like users, are stored in some non-standard fashion which prevents `DeleteObjects` from finding them. Whatever the reason, but explicitly converting the user to a scripted object with a given name, and passing that given name to the `DeleteObjects` method, it works.

I am a little concerned that I do not know *why* it works. The other concern is that it doesn't show up in the official documentation of the `TSqlModel` object:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.tsqlmodel_methods(v=sql.120).aspx

But it does work. At least, so far.

Answer (score 0):

DeleteObject caught me out the same way :) - it only deletes scripts added using AddOrUpdate when you also pass in a script name and Delete uses the same script name.

What you need to do is create a new model and add in everything except the things you want to delete.

Why do you want to delete a login? If you don't want it to be deployed you can use a deployment contributor like my one here to exclude the login at deployment time:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/HOWTO-Filter-Dacpac-Deployments

Ed

Comment: I did try using the approach outlined at agilesql.club but it caused me more problems. Some of the objects in the database were referencing tables in the master db and so the build of the filtered DACPAC failed. However, I did discover that if I use the ConvertToScriptedObject method prior to deleting the object, it worked. I'll try and post my own solution shortly.